# A strong converse to Hilbert's basis theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a multiplicative identity such that there is a finitely generated $R$-algebra that is Noetherian. Is $R$ Noetherian then?

I tried to prove this using the fact that the homomorphic image of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian but I can not find an ideal the quotient by which is isomorphic to $R$ for general finitely generated algebras. In some special cases, that can be done (e.g. for the free polynomial algebra take the ideal $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$).

Comment: This is not true. Try thinking of a counterexample. What is true is that if $R$ is a subring of a Noetherian ring finite over $R$, then $R$ is also Noetherian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be any non-zero ring.  If you are willing to accept the existence of maximal ideals, then there's always a finitely generated non-zero $R$-algebra $S$ which is noetherian.

Just take $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal of $R$ and then $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is, being a field, noetherian.

Therefore *every non-noetherian ring will still have finite non-zero morphisms to noetherian rings*

Note that noetherianity won't descend down finitely presented morphisms either.  Continuing with the reasoning from maximal ideals, there are many non-noetherian rings which have finitely generated maximal ideals (e.g. construct an appropriate rank > 1 valuation domain).

Comment: Or, just use the zero ring.

Comment: does there exist a non-Noetherian (commutative unital) ring such that there is no finitely presented algebra over it that is Noetherian?

Comment: @hello no, as Eric Wofsey just said, there's always the zero ring, which is finitely presented over every ring.

Comment: I was just trying to edit the comment to make it less trivial. Does there exist a ring $R$ such that the quotient of $R$ by any proper finitely-generated ideal is not Noetherian and such that the quotient of $R[x_1,\dots, x_d]$ for any positive integer $d$ by a proper finitely-generated ideal is not Noetherian?

Comment: @How about a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables?